# Quantum Computation and its threats

Tags: encryption, passwords, cryptography, penetration-test

Since Quantum Computers has potential to become super computers of next generation. will that make cryptography obsolete..?

Answer (score 2):

Quantum computers do offer more efficient attacks against some methods of encryption. For example, [Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor's_algorithm), when combined with a quantum computer, will allow faster prime factorization of semi-primes. This, in particular, would allow for faster attacks against algorithms such as RSA that depend on the hardness of semi-prime factorization.

However, this does not imply that all cryptography will be obsolete.  [Post-quantum cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-quantum_cryptography) specifically focuses on algorithms that will remain secure against the properties of quantum computers. Furthermore, [quantum cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_cryptography) specifically makes it possible to use quantum physics to perform cryptographic operations in new (sometimes more secure) ways.